# Handle Nested Context Providers

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, react-context

I have a few nested Context Providers in my app that look like this

```
export const LangContext = React.createContext("javascript");
export const FontContext = React.createContext("mono-space");
export const FontSizeContext = React.createContext("16px");

const Store = ({ children }) => {
  const [lang, setLang] = useState("javascript");
  const [font, setFont] = useState("mono-space");
  const [fontSize, setFontSize] = useState("16px");
  return (
      <LangContext.Provider value={[lang, setLang]}>
        <FontContext.Provider value={[font, setFont]}>
          <FontSizeContext.Provider value={[fontSize, setFontSize]}>
              {children}
          </FontSizeContext.Provider>
        </FontContext.Provider>
      </LangContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

I'm sure this is a bad practice but I'm not sure how to handle this. I want to be able to create a single context provider for all the contexts.

Comment: this is not a bad practice. Infact you might need to break them further down if you use reducers with state and dispatch contexts. The thing to note is, if our component needs only for example font context values, it shouldnt rerender on lang-context updates. So its better to break up contexts. However you might want to logically group the contexts. For example all the ones you have mentioned seem like they belong to a singl theme context

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply use a single provider and pass on the required values as an object:

```
export const StoreContext = React.createContext({});
const Store = ({ children }) => {
  const [lang, setLang] = useState("javascript");
  const [font, setFont] = useState("mono-space");
  const [fontSize, setFontSize] = useState("16px");
  return (
      <StoreContext.Provider value={{lang, setLang, font, setFont, fontSize, setFontSize}}>
              {children}
      </StoreContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

Also instead of using `useState` you could modify the above to use `useReducer` and make the API even simpler:

```js
const initialState= {
   lang: 'javascript',
   font: 'mono-space',
   fontSize: '16px',
}

const reducer = (state, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'SET_LANG': return {...state, lang: action.payload}
        case 'SET_FONT': return {...state, font: action.payload}
        case 'SET_FONTSIZE': return {...state, fontSize: action.payload}
        default: return state;
    }
}
export const StoreContext = React.createContext({});
const Store = ({ children }) => {
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, initialState);
  return (
      <StoreContext.Provider value={[state, dispatch]}>
              {children}
      </StoreContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

and in the child you can use it like:

```
const Child = () => {
    const [state, dispatch] = useContext(StoreContext);
    const handleChange = (size) => {
         dispatch({type: 'SET_FONTSIZE', payload: size})
    }
    ....
}
```

Comment: There is a reason why people use multiple providers! e.g. only those consumers, whose providers `value` has changed will re-render. With your current syntax that is ALL THE TIME FOR EVERYTHING (the question code has the same issues), e.g. use `useMemo` or a separate state like here: https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html#caveats

Answer (score 0):

I guess it's fine, I also end up with many `Context`'s. But it's not ideal, and poor structure of the app.

I recommend reading Kent C. Dodds' [Application State Management](https://kentcdodds.com/blog/application-state-management-with-react) which discusses `Context`, the problem of *prop-drilling* and then also [points to a Youtube-video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3XaXKiXtNjw) that explains *Component composition*, which I think is a good design pattern that in the long run might lead to needing less `Context`'s and a managing state better.

I also recommend reading [How to use React Context effectively](https://kentcdodds.com/blog/how-to-use-react-context-effectively)